# ThingsBoard Hybrid mode

Tags: postgresql, cassandra, thingsboard

I can read in thingsboard configuration documentation (https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/config/), in "Common database parameters" section, that database.ts.type can be sql or cassandra, and cassandra should be used for hybrid mode. what's that hybrid mode?
Do you mean that database.entities.type can be sql (postgres) and database.ts.type can be cassandra? and 
vice versa?
what's the recommanded install? All on cassandra?

Many thanks,

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here:

https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/ ,  section "SQL vs NoSQL vs Hybrid database approach"

ThingsBard uses database to store entities (devices, assets, customers, dashboards, etc) and telemetry data (attributes, timeseries sensor readings, statistics, events). Platform supports three database options at the moment:

- SQL - Stores all entities and telemetry in SQL database. ThingsBoard authors recommend to use PostgreSQL and this is the main SQL database that ThingsBoard supports. It is possible to use HSQLDB for local development purposes. We do not recommend to use HSQLDB for anything except running tests and launching dev instance that has minimum possible load.
- NoSQL - Stores all entities and telemetry in NoSQL database. ThingsBoard authors recommend to use Cassandra and this is the only NoSQL database that ThingsBoard supports at the moment. However, due to a lot of interest to deployments with managed databases, we plan to introduce support on AWS DynamoDB in v2.3.
- Hybrid - Stores all entities in SQL database and all telemetry in NoSQL database.